# Regex, how to remove all non-alphanumeric except colon in a 12/24 hour timestamp?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

```
Today, 3:30pm - Group Meeting to discuss "big idea"
```

How do you construct a regex such that after parsing it would return:

```
Today 3:30pm Group Meeting to discuss big idea
```

I would like it to remove all non-alphanumeric characters except for those that appear in a 12 or 24 hour time stamp.

Comment: I am using python. Sorry, should have mentioned it.

Comment: IronPython (with .NET) or "normal" Python?

Comment: To be more clear (hopefully)

If string is `Today, 3:30pm - Group Meeting: to discuss "big idea"`

I would like `Today 3:30pm Group Meeting to discuss big idea`

The only non-alphanumeric character I would like left behind after the replace is the colon in a timestamp.

Comment: Normal python found in Ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# this: D:DD, DD:DDam/pm 12/24 hr
re = r':(?=..(?<!\d:\d\d))|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ](?<!:)'
```

A colon must be preceded by at least one digit and followed by at least two digits: then it's a time. All other colons will be considered textual colons.

#### How it works

```
:              // match a colon
(?=..          // match but not capture two chars
  (?<!         // start a negative look-behind group (if it matches, the whole fails)
    \d:\d\d    // time stamp
  )            // end neg. look behind
)              // end non-capture two chars
|              // or
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]  // match anything not digits or letters
(?<!:)         // that isn't a colon
```

Then when applied to this silly text:

```
Today, 3:30pm - Group 1,2,3 Meeting to di4sc::uss3: 2:3:4 "big idea" on 03:33pm or 16:47 is also good
```

...changes it into:

```
Today, 3:30pm  Group 123 Meeting to di4scuss3 234 big idea on 03:33pm or 16:47 is also good
```

Comment: @Cadwag, you said you got an error about neg look forward/behind must be fixed width only. That's a restriction of many regex flavors (not .NET though). I'll update my answer with that in mind.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.

I am trying your solution in Unix normal python using the python example given by 'Bryan McLemore'. So using your solution, it the 3rd line looks like `re.sub(r'(<![012]?\d):(>!\d\d(?:[ap]m)?)|[^A-Za-z\d: ]', '', x)`

But it doesn't seem to do anything when I run it. 

I'm sorry for all the hassle. I'm just starting out with python and have never been very good with regex. 

Thanks again

Comment: Nice work Abel, just testing it though, it doesn't seem to match the colon in "3:3".

Comment: @J-P: is that testing in Python or in .NET? And did you use my original design, because then: indeed, it would consider 3:3 as a time.

Comment: @Cadwag: if you've trouble with regexes, check this list of online regex testers: http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/overview-of-online-regular-expression-testers/. PCRE is what I believe Python uses internally.

Comment: Hmm, I thought PCRE lookbehinds were constructed like `(?<!` ... not `(<!`

Comment: Thanks, J-P, that was exactly my mistake! (and a few others, updating now to correct them)

Comment: Abel, hats off to you. Really went above and beyond the call of duty there. Your latest solution seems to work perfectly!

Seriously, thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of help. Make sure to check the explanation, it may help ;-) This proofs very helpful when dealing with this kind of stuff (visualizer): http://regex.powertoy.org/ (turn it into Perl mode)

Comment: This will keep colons at the last two positions in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Python.

```
import string
punct=string.punctuation
s='Today, 3:30pm - Group Meeting:am to discuss "big idea" by our madam'
for item in s.split():
    try:
        t=time.strptime(item,"%H:%M%p")
    except:
        item=''.join([ i for i in item if i not in punct])
    else:
        item=item
    print item,
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
Today 3:30pm  Group Meetingam to discuss big idea by our madam

# change to s='Today, 15:30pm - Group 1,2,3 Meeting to di4sc::uss3: 2:3:4 "big idea" on 03:33pm or 16:47 is also good'

$ ./python.py
Today 15:30pm  Group 123 Meeting to di4scuss3 234 big idea on 03:33pm or 1647 is also good
```

NB: Method should be improved to check for valid time only when necessary(by imposing conditions) , but i will leave it as that for now.

Comment: Nice approach, but you need a few more tweaks to handle the 24-hour time stamp requirement ("15:30" instead of "3:30pm")

Comment: what do you mean? it doesn't matter right? %H is from 00 to 24 inclusive.

Comment: `16:47` becomes `1647` in your example, I think that's what Ned means.

Comment: Btw, though it isn't specified in the q., my solution allows time in text, yours splits on word boundaries prior to that: "This12:40 is late" is silly of course, not sure how the OP would want to deal with that (my solution leaves the colon, yours will delete it).

Comment: @abel, i see. anyway, there are much to take care of since we are only working on limited data in this case. I will just leave it as that.

Comment: +1 for the alternative non-regex approach anyway! Nice example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you'd like to keep spaces as well, and this implementation is in python, but it's PCRE so it should be portable.

```
import re
x = u'Today, 3:30pm - Group Meeting to discuss "big idea"'
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9: ]', '', x)
```

Output: 'Today 3:30pm  Group Meeting to discuss big idea'

for a slightly cleaner answer (no double spaces)

```
import re
x = u'Today, 3:30pm - Group Meeting to discuss "big idea"'
tmp = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9: ]', '', x)
re.sub(r'[ ]+', ' ', tmp)
```

Output: 'Today 3:30pm Group Meeting to discuss big idea'

Comment: What about "Today, 3:30pm - Group meeting: discuss big idea" - the colon after "meeting" won't be removed.

Comment: @Cadwag, this solution removes colons even when they are outside of timestamps. Surely you don't want this?

Comment: Yea, in my excitement I seem to have acted prematurely. But it seems to act as Greg Hewgill says - leaving colons that are outside of timestamps

Comment: Not sure about Python, but my C# solution below might solve this problem with neg. look forward / backward. Also check Rubens Farias solution, that should work with Python too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try, in Javascript:

```
var re = /(\W+(?!\d{2}[ap]m))/gi;
var input = 'Today, 3:30pm - Group Meeting to discuss "big idea"';
alert(input.replace(re, " "))
```

Comment: Interesting how many solutions are given. You replace any non-word character with a space, that means `discuss "big idea"` becomes `discuss  big idea ` (i.e., extra spaces). Use something like `/(( )|\W)(?!\d{2})/g;` and `.replace(re, "$2")` (or was it `\1` in JS?). This will leave the spaces and remove the rest. I call this "conditional replacement".

Comment: hmm, yet another Markdown in comments bug: the extra space in `discuss  big` got lost...

Comment: interesting approach, Abel, ty

Answer (score 0):

Correct regexp to do that would be:

```
'(?<!\d):|:(?!\d\d)|[^a-zA-Z0-9 :]'
```

Answer (score -1):

> > > s="Call me, my dear, at 3:30"
> > >
> > > re.sub(r'[^\w :]','',s)

'Call me my dear at 3:30'

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Colons that are not part of a timestamp should be removed.   And the formatting needs a lot of work, too.